# Enable overriding settings option not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've made asynchronous type pages. so I want to configure GTM for a virtual pageview.

[image: GA Setting]

I added nothing but only Tracking ID on the GA variable config and tried to override setting of each virtual page.

[image]
[image]

However, in preview mode, the settings were not applicable at all. Is there anything I missing?

extra desc:

I realized that 'GA settings' should not be filled for the overriding and It makes some changes. but fields settings are still not working

Comment: Did you publish the container?

Comment: yes, publishing changes nothing.

Comment: There is a GA variable state on the screenshot in your question and what is the state of entire tag? Can you check if the data is sent to Google Analytics by looking for it in GA or Network panel of your browser?

Comment: I found http requests sending new configuration in Network panel. I can't understand why GTM debug panel don't reflect these changes. Anyway It seems to have been settled. Thank you so much